# Как отключить METRO в Windows Server 2012 R2?

Tags: windows-server, windows-server-2012

Собственно добавить нечего:
Как отключить METRO в Windows Server 2012 R2 и вернуть более менее нормальный Пуск?

Comment: Используйте программку Classic Shell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Отключить интерфейс METRO нельзя, т.к. он является важной управляющей частью Windows 8/Server 2012.
Для того, чтобы вернуть в ОС нормальный пуск, устанавливают сторонние приложения. Так, например, наиболее популярное [Classic Shell](http://www.classicshell.net) возвращает меню и предлагает различное его оформление. В системных требованиях на странице значится ваша редакция ОС Windows - Server 2012 R2.